# Checking if a matrix defines a bounded operator

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

Does this matrix define a bounded operator from $\ell^2$ to $\ell^2$?

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  & \frac { 1 }{ 3 } & ...  \\ -1 & 0 & 1  & \frac { 1 }{ 2 } & ... \\ -\frac { 1 }{ 2 } & -1 & 0  & 1 & ...\\ ... & ... & ... & ...& ... \end{pmatrix}

It looks similar to a Hilbert matrix, $(\frac{1}{i+j-1})_{i,j}$ (which defines a bounded operator), but not exactly the same...

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Such a matrix is called a Toeplitz matrix. There is a fascinating result on the boundedness of such matrices.

> A Toeplitz matrix \begin{pmatrix} a_0 & a_{-1} & a_{-2}  & a_{-3} & ...  \\ a_1 & a_0 & a_{-1}  & a_{-2} & ... \\ a_2 & a_1 & a_0  & a_{-1} & ...\\ ... & ... & ... & ...& ... \end{pmatrix} is a bounded operator $\ell^2\to\ell^2$ if and only if there exists a bounded function $f\colon S^1\to\mathbb C$ such that $$a_n=\int_{S^1}\overline{z^n}f(z)~dz=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\pi t(n+1)}f(e^{it})~dt.$$ That is to say, that the $a_n$'s are the Fourier coefficients of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, whz! The resulting function would be f(t)=$\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus{0}}\frac{1}{n}e^{int}$. Is it obviously bounded? I'm not sure...

Comment: What happens at $t=0$?

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman : Have you tried starting with $\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}/n=1/(1-z)$?

Comment: whz, at $t=0$ we get the harmonnic series, which diverges...
T.A.E., that leads us to log(1-z).

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman : One can construct a continuous function on $[-\pi,\pi]$ whose Fourier series diverges at $0$. So you have to be a little careful in the conclusions you draw from the divergence of the Fourier series at just one point. The log is a good way to analyze this problem.